# idlj Ignoring "#pragma prefix"

Tags: java, corba, idl

I have an IDL file that has a "#pragma prefix" directive, but whenever I use idlj to build the Java code, it ignores this and generates an _id without the prefix specified.  This is a big problem because when _is_a is used, it always returns false, since my generated code does not contain the expected prefix.  Please help!  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which vendor's corba implementation and runtime are you using?

Comment: Unfortunately, legacy Avaya CORBA stuff for PDS R12 with Java 1.2.  I wish there were more people out there still working on these machines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up being the culprit on this one.  I was just not doing enough checks and balances and it ended up some of the IDL files I was using didn't even have the #pragma prefix statement in them.

Comment: Ah, problem between keyboard and chair.  Glad you got it working.